# DropDownListFor dentro de un bucle no recupera el valor seleccionado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, dropdownlist

tengo el siguiente código.
Primero los siguientes modelos (por la facilidad de lectura he reducido al mínimo las clases, en el codigo tienen más atributos):

```
public class ConfiguradorYears
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public List<ConfiguracionSemana> confSemana { get; set; }
    }
```

Esta contiene

```
public class ConfiguracionSemana
{
    public int ID { get; set; } 
    public Categoria categoria { get; set; }
    public int? categoriaId { get; set; } 
}
```

En el controlador se rellena un viewmodel que cargará el DDL:

```
    private void loadVM()
    {

        List<SelectListItem> lstCategorias = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var Categorias = db.Categorias.ToList();

        lstCategorias.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = "-", Value = "-1" });

        foreach (var item in Categorias)
        {
            lstCategorias.Add(new SelectListItem() { Text = item.Nombre, Value = item.ID.ToString() });
        }

        ViewBag.Categorias = lstCategorias;
    }
```

Este método se llama, de momento, siempre antes de devolver una vista, para asegurarme de que están cargados los valores.
En la vista tengo lo siguiente:

```
<div class="table">
            @if (Model.confSemana != null)
            {
                for (var i = 0; i < Model.confSemana.Count; i++)
                {

                    <div class="col-md-2">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.confSemana[i].categoriaId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Categorias, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control", @style = "width:100%" }) 

                    </div>
                }
            }
```

El caso es los valores se pasan correctamente, si pongo puntos de interrupción veo que **model.confSemana[i].categoriaId** es el valor que espero, de igual forma, si cambio el valor y devuelvo los datos al controlador, estos son correctos. El problema es que al cargar esta página el valor seleccionado del DDL no se corresponde a **model.confSemana[i].categoriaId**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El caso es que tengo el mismo código funcionando, pero sin que esté dentro de un bucle, así que me pregunto si es que he pasado algo por alto.
Un saludo.

Comment: El código parece correcto, el problema debe estar en otro lado